# Can we use Delegates in Getters

Tags: c#, class, getter-setter

We know that, it is possible to use Lambda functions as getters like,

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get => _name;
}
```

But, can we make use of anonymous functions with delegates as getters like,

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get => delegate { return _name; };
}
```

It's getting compilation errors.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Sweeper, actually I  got this question from a student. I had never even think of this.

Comment: You cannot use it the way you want, because it's just syntactically wrong. And we cannot guess from a wrong result what your desired correct result is. Please describe what you *want* to do, so we can help you achieve it.

Comment: `string Name => _name` and string `Name { get => _name }` are not delegates, they just look like them. They just use the same method body syntax eg `() { return X;}` vs `() => x;`. The method body can do anything which is valid inside a method body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delegate are nothing but a pointer to a method (overly simplified, however you can find the detailed information here [Using Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates)). So the answer is yes.

You can use *delegates*, *actions*, *funcs* etc.

I give you the world's most contrived example:

```
private static string _name = "bob";

public delegate string Del(string message);

public static string DoSomething(string message) => message + "1";

private static readonly Del Handler = DoSomething;

public string Name
{
    get => Handler(_name);
}
```